# Rails change route system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner rails developer. I have this question:
I've a resource in my routes.
resource

```
  resources :events, only: [:index, :show, :comment] do
    member do
      post :comment
      get :will_go
    end
  end
```

then in Event model I've this relation
event belongs_to city
and in the city model
city has_many events

I using friendly_id gem, for do my own routes. Now i have link to event like:
http://localhost:3000/events/moscow/concert_of_madonna/49
where 
moscow - is the title of city
concert_of_madonna - is slug of title of event
49 is event id

But we need to do something like this:
http://localhost:3000/moscow/events/concert_of_madonna/49
so i need to switch city title and resource .

I know that I can do it with routes, but i have no success.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `scope`:

```
scope ':city' do
  resources :events, only: [:index, :show, :comment] do
    member do
      post :comment
      get :will_go
    end
  end
end
```